# Odoo 14 render template with model records

Tags: html, xml, odoo, qweb

I am new to the QWeb template engine, and I am trying to use the attributes of a model record that I passed via the `request.render` function for the class name.

For example:

In my Web Controller, I respond with:

```
return request.render('sync.product_sync', {'odoo_products': products_odoo})
```

Now, I want to insert the `id` attribute of every >products_odoo< in the class tag of a div:

```
<t t-foreach="odoo_products" t-as="odoo_prod">
    <div class="odoo_prod_... {{ odoo_prod.id }}"> <t t-esc="odoo_prod.name"/> </div>
</t>
```

results in

```
<div class="odoo_prod_... {{ odoo_prod.id }}"> Productname 1 </div>
<div class="odoo_prod_... {{ odoo_prod.id }}"> Productname 2 </div>
<div class="odoo_prod_... {{ odoo_prod.id }}"> Productname 3 </div>
<div class="odoo_prod_... {{ odoo_prod.id }}"> Productname 4 </div>
... 
...
```

I just found that _index syntax that not given me the result I want...

Thanks

Comment: That is the result ?

Comment: No! <t t-esc="odoo_prod.name"/> got replaced by the template engine as well as <t t-foreach="odoo_products" t-as="odoo_prod"> loops over all "odoo_products".
I just played around with taht {{ ... }} notation i know from other engines

Comment: Could you add the result return by this code (The html) please?

Comment: sure, i added it to the questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you add class= but Odoo will process on attribute only when the attribute is prefixed by t-attf-$name.

In your case is t-attf-class="odoo_prod_... {{ odoo_prod.id }}"

[More information](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/fr/developer/reference/qweb.html#attributes)

Example:

```
<t t-foreach="[1, 2, 3]" t-as="item">
    <li t-attf-class="row {{ (item_index % 2 === 0) ? 'even' : 'odd' }}">
        <t t-esc="item"/>
    </li>
</t>
```

Comment: Hey jo541, thank you for u explanation. That feature was not clear in the docs. So i think its important to point out that its also possible to get the attributes of a model like `{{ odoo_prod.id }}` inside the `t-attf-$name` string. Anyway, thank you! :)